# What is this concept in OOP called and how dangerous is it in Python?

Tags: python, oop, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a Selenium application for automating some tasks. It runs infinitely and the site I'm using it on is very unstable, meaning I need to wrap everything in my own wait wrapper which checks for unexpected conditions. The site can randomly give errors or not advance from one page from another, so I solved it kind of like this:

I have a class where all of the logic is being executed and a navigation controller after some action is done:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.state = "ACTION1"
        ...
    
    def start(self):
        self.driver.get(...)
        self.navigation_controller()

    def navigation_controller(self):
        self.check_for_unexpected_conditions(cameFrom=self.state)

        if self.state == "ACTION1":
            if len(self.driver.find(...) > 0):
                self.state = "ACTION2"
                self.advance()
```

In the `check_for_unexpected_conditions` method if something is wrong it calls the method `start`. And practices like this are all over my code, where I call methods to check for unexpected behavior and I call the `start` method (or any other method for that matter, it doesn't matter).

**What I'm worried about:**

Because I'm constantly calling other methods from different places, not finishing themselves anywhere I'm afraid this is going to result in infinite nesting of methods on top of each other. Meaning I'm worried I'm doing something like this:

```
>>> def a():
...     while True:
...             a()
```

Using my example: `navigation_controller` calls `check_for_unexpected_conditions` which calls `start` to restart everything, the code for e.g. runs normally for 10 minutes until the driver runs into some unexpected condition along the way and calls `start` again. I'm worried that Python remembers all these exectuions because it's expecting to return from them and continue executing the original code:

```
    def navigation_controller(self):
        self.check_for_unexpected_conditions(cameFrom=self.state) <-- CALLED
        <-- WAITING TO REACH HERE, BUT NEVER WILL

        if self.state == "ACTION1":
            if len(self.driver.find(...) > 0):
                self.state = "ACTION2"
                self.advance()
```

Is this a valid concern? How can I prevent it?

I expect Python to infinitely nest methods on top of each other.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

Comment: Literally. Thank you

Comment: This resembles continuation-passing style (or maybe just mutual recursion). The danger is the same as any other recursive function: you could blow up the stack before any of your functions actually return.

Comment: Then, if I got it correctly -- the easiest solution would be to wrap all of this in a while True loop (initialize a new Session each time and start), and if there are any unexpected conditions the method - just return.